# Linux one-liner to batch find all files of a name and duplicate and rename them

Tags: linux, file, duplicates, rename

In my folder tree of music, artists, and albums and mp3 files, there is a file called cover.jpg for each album.

I want to find all these cover.jpg files and copy them with a new name, folder.jpg. So each album directory in the tree now has both a file named cover.jpg and a copy of it name folder.jpg.

In my monkeying around I tried:

```
 find . -iname "*cover.jpg*" -exec cp cover.jpg folder.jpg '{}' \;
```

But I got "not a directory" messages like the following:

cp: target './Alternative/Aimee Mann/1995 - I'''m With Stupid (MP3)/cover.jpg': Not a directory

Answer (score 0):

You're finding `-iname "*cover.jpg*"` so `{}` is going to be "/Alternative/Aimee Mann/1995 - I'm With Stupid (MP3)/cover.jpg" (i.e. cover.jpg on the end). Also, you're not "in" the folder, so your cp won't find the right file.

Would something like `find . -type d -exec cd "{}"; cp cover.jpg folder.jpg \;` work ? As in go into each directory and copy cover.jpg to folder.jpg - worst case scenario is that cover.jpg doesn't exist and the cp fail in those directories.

[edit] find doesn't let you join shell commands like that but something like: `find . -type d -exec bash -c 'cd $0; cp cover.jpg folder.jpg' {}  \;` should do it.

Comment: I gave it a try from the root of my music folder and got:

find: missing argument to `-exec'
cp: target ';': No such file or directory

Comment: yeah - just checked. "exec" doesn't let you chain commands like that. you could put the cd ...; cp into a script and run that via exec - but that's not a good oneliner. Likewise you could do a shell for loop on all the dirs found by the find, but that's not a great one liner either.